# Making two method calls in the same request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

A brief overview of what I am trying to accomplish:

On the front-end, a user is able to edit information about their account with the use of a form. That form is then sent to the same HTTP request regardless of how many fields have been edited/touched.

My thinking is that the request would then handle which fields to edit. This logic seems sound to me except I am unsure about how to return confirmation data. For example, how would it know when all requests have been completed/which confirmation and error messages to display.

```
//Change information route
router.post('/changeinformation', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
    const changeInfo = {
        changeEmail: req.body.changeEmail,
        changeUsername: req.body.changeUsername
    };

    if(changeInfo.changeUsername === true) {
        const userInfo = {
            email: req.body.email,
            currentEmail: req.body.currentEmail
        };
        Artist.getArtistByEmail(userInfo.email, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (user) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Email already exists'});
            }
            else {
                Artist.changeEmail(userInfo, (err, callback) => {
                    if (callback) {
                        console.log(callback);
                        return res.json({success: true, msg: 'Email has been changed successfully'});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    if(changeInfo.changeUsername === true) {
        //Checks if username exists
        const nameInfo = {
            name: req.body.name,
            currentName: req.body.currentName
        };
        Artist.getArtistByName(userInfo.name, (err, user) =>
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (user) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Name already exists'});
            }
            else
            {
                Artist.changeName(userInfo, (err, callback) => {
                    if(callback)
                    {
                        console.log(callback);
                        return res.json({success: true, msg: 'Name has been changed successfully'});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I apologize if this may seem obvious to some. I am still learning and am unsure about how to handle this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making multiple calls here is really not needed, or anywhere near efficient. Instead of making multiple calls, you build the query and update according to the selected options.

It's also completely unnecessary to construct different methods for modifying each property. When expressed correctly, the standard mongoose ( actually really MongoDB ) methods should be descriptive enough of the intended function. Doing otherwise is cumbersome and impractical, and building query options instead of specific property calls is what you usually mean to do:

```
router.post('/changeinformation',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {

  let query = { },
      update = { $set: { } };

  if ( req.body.changeEmail ) {
    query['email'] = req.body.currentEmail;   // presuming this is current
    update.$set['email'] = req.body.email;
  }

  if ( req.body.changeUsername ) {
    query['name'] = req.body.currentName;
    update.$set['name'] = req.body.name;
  }

  // One call only
  User.update(query,update,(err,result) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === 11000) {     // Duplicate key error
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'email or name already exists' });
      } else {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: err.message });
      }
    } else {
      if ( result.n === 0 ) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Requested details not found' });
      } else {
        res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Details updated successfully' });
      }
    }

  });

});
```

So instead of branching off and making different calls, you simply inspect the provided options and build the query and update statements from there. These are "by-design" just regular object representations and like any object you simply manipulate the structure to construct them.

The first main departure here is the usage of queries for "checking the existence of the target values" for the changes. That's really inefficient. What you are really asking for is that these values instead be "unique" so that no other objects in the collection can share the same `name` or `email`. The way you enforce this is by using "indexes":

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
  ...
});
```

Those `"unique"` properties in the schema tell mongoose to create an index on that property that is "unique". If you try to add more than one of the same value in the collection ( i.e change a user name to the same value as an existing entry ) then this will throw a "duplicate key error", which we can catch by the error code and respond accordingly.

So that is what the code does, by testing the error code returned and giving the appropriate message in response when it was identified as a duplicate key error:

```
      if (err.code === 11000) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'email or name already exists' });
      } else {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: err.message });
      }
```

That's a lot more direct than making a separate query to test if the target value is already there. Also it's far more reliable, as it is possible that in between your "query" and the subsequent "update" in your current code, something else can actually change the data. So without enforcing unique indexes and checking for the error you run the risk of creating duplicates. So use the right tool for the right job.

The other check in here is of course to see if anything was matched by the update at all. This is always contained in the response object from the [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) under the `n` property, which denotes the number of documents the condition actually matched.

As for the messages themselves, you can leave them "as is" and I find that perfectly reasonable personally, or you can alternately use similar branching logic on the request parameters as with the statement construction to determine the specific message content to return.

As an example:

```
let errStr = (req.body.changeEmail && req.body.changeUsername)
  ? "email or name" 
  : ( req.body.changeEmail ) ? "email" : "name";
res.json({ success: false, msg: `${errStr} already exists` });
```

And hopefully you get the general idea.

But it's all a lot better than trying to chain different calls together and making multiple requests when you really do not need to.

---

As a sidenote, we actually have more modern and recommended ways of dealing with things than using callback nesting. Promises have been around for some time, and you also really should be working in an environment supporting [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax, as any nodejs v8.x.x release does and that is actually about to become the Long Term Support (LTS) version:

```
router.post('/changeinformation',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), async (req, res) => {

  let query = { },
      update = { $set: { } };

  if ( req.body.changeEmail ) {
    query['email'] = req.body.currentEmail;   // presuming this is current
    update.$set['email'] = req.body.email;
  }

  if ( req.body.changeUsername ) {
    query['name'] = req.body.currentName;
    update.$set['name'] = req.body.name;
  }

  try {
    let result = await User.update(query,update);

    if ( result.n === 0 ) {
      let msgStr = (req.body.changeEmail && req.body.changeUsername)
        ? "email or name"
        : ( req.body.changeEmail ) ? "email" : "name";
      res.json({ success: false, msg: `Requested ${msgStr} not found` });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Details updated successfully' });
    }

  } catch(e) {
    if (e.code === 11000) {
      let errStr = (req.body.changeEmail && req.body.changeUsername)
        ? "email or name"
        : ( req.body.changeEmail ) ? "email" : "name";
      res.json({ success: false, msg: `${errStr} already exists` });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: false, msg: e.message });
    }
  }
});
```

It really comes into it's own when you actually do have a chain of async functions to resolve, and what we are really trying to avoid in this instance. But the general case of even including the [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block does at the very least have a more logical flow and does improve readability of the code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there was something fundamentally wrong with the way I was doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first `if(changeInfo.changeUsername === true)` should be `if(changeInfo.changeEmail === true)` following your logic.